# I am using Angular with NGRX.If i access my angular app in multiple tabs of the same browser will the apps point to single NGRX instance or not?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I want to access my localhost:9000 in multiple tabs.if i open it in 3 tabs will all those 3 tabs point to single NGRX instance or each tab of localhost will have its dedicated NGRX instance?

I did not try it yet

Comment: They won't by default, but you can handle that using `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

When you open your Angular application with NgRx in multiple tabs, each tab will have its dedicated NgRx instance. This is because each tab runs in a separate JavaScript runtime environment, and the state in one tab is not shared with the others.

If you need to share state or communicate between the tabs, you can use techniques like `localStorage`, `sessionStorage`, or `BroadcastChannel`. However, by default, each tab will have its own separate instance of the NgRx store.

More information on using BroadcastChannel in Angular [here](https://www.acagroup.be/en/blog/how-to-use-the-broadcastchannel-api-angular/).